# Banning search terms

Tags: search, keyword, adsense

This is my first post here, sorry if I am doing it wrong. I've already searched for my question and could not find it.

I run a video meta-search engine.

I was recently banned from Google Adsense for having pages that contained 'adult content' and 'adult keywords'.

I would like to know how to ban the search of words like 'sex' on my site. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, when they click search, or press enter, the "method" that is called should just search the string for those keywords. If it has one that's blocked, don't let it display the results. One note is that there are many videos that are adult, but don't have a name that would reflect it. You may consider filtering the results by there content rating.